# How to remove dead records in a collection

Tags: arangodb

in my collections are more dead records than alive records. Those dead records seem to use a lot of memory in my system. They do not automatically become removed, even not after shutdowns of the server.

Does anybody know how I can remove those from the system?

Comment: Is this still a problem? Normally the garbage collection should automatically remove dead records

Comment: When shall the GC automatically start? (time triggered, low-memory-triggered, Num-if-Event-triggered, ...)

Comment: The garbage collection is executed per collection datafile. A garbage collection should be executed (only) if the collection is loaded, and a datafile contains at least 128 KB dead elements or 10 % dead elements. ArangoDB should check for GC periodically and automatically, provided the collection is loaded and its `doCompact` property is not set to `false`.

Comment: Thank you. This background understanding makes the interpretation of my observations easier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make it as an answer for future generations:

stj's answer is correct!

The garbage collection of ArangoDB should automatically remove dead records.

ArangoDB checks for garbage collection periodically and automatically, IF the collection is loaded and the `doCompact`property is not set to `false`.
In addition a datafile in the loaded collection should have at least 128 KB dead elements - or at minimum 10%!

Comment: Can we disable the revisions altogether ? We have had a performance issue with doCompact set to true so we have to use doCompact as false But these causes giga bytes of dead documents.